# How to add query data to an array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to loop through data using queries to a REST endpoint then add this to an array and write it out to a csv `tempArray` is empty on `end`

```
var fastcsv = require('fast-csv');  
var tempArray=[];
conn.login(logincred, loginpass, function(err, res) {
    fastcsv.fromPath("accounts.csv").on("data", function(csvrow){
        conn.query("SELECT Id, Name, PersonEmail FROM Account WHERE PersonEmail = '" + csvrow[2] + "' LIMIT 1" , function(err, res) {
            if (err){ 
                console.log(err);
            }
            csvrow[3] = res.records[0].Id
            tempArray.push(csvrow);
            console.log(tempArray)
        });
    }).on('end',function() {
        console.log('CSV file successfully processed');
        console.log(tempArray)
        //want to write csv here
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as the docs in fast-csv it should be only this:

```
var fastcsv = require('fast-csv');  
var tempArray=[];
conn.login(logincred, loginpass, function(err, res) {
    fastcsv.fromPath("accounts.csv").on("data", function(csvrow){
        conn.query("SELECT Id, Name, PersonEmail FROM Account WHERE PersonEmail = '" + csvrow[2] + "' LIMIT 1" , function(err, res) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            csvrow[3] = res.records[0].Id
            tempArray.push(csvrow);
            console.log(tempArray)
        });


    })
    .on('end',function() {
        console.log('CSV file successfully processed');
        console.log(tempArray)
        fastcsv.writeToPath("whatever.csv", tempArray, {headers: true})
            .on("finish", function() {
                console.log("done!");
            });
    });
});
```

you can try the writing code with this small node program:

```
var csv = require('fast-csv');
var tempArray = [['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'], ['ddd', 'eee', 'fff']];
csv.writeToPath("./whatever.csv", tempArray, {headers: true})
    .on("finish", function() {
        console.log("done!");
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for responding.  I have tried this approach the issue is the array "tempArray' is empty on 'end'.  It console logs out during the loop but at the end it's empty.  It doesn't seem to be available outside the conn.query().

Comment: That's because query is a async operation. So you command a series of queries (one per line) and the fast-csv "end" event concludes before the queries start. So when they start, you see the lines, but the end event already happened. I don't have time to solve this right now. A bit later I'll try to solve it if you don't come with a solution first.

Answer (score 0):

I sorted it out Nelson was correct it was basically a race condition.  I put the 'end' wich works better as finish inside the conn.query() loop.

```
    fastcsv.fromPath("accounts.csv").on("data", function(csvrow){
        conn.query("SELECT Id, Name, PersonEmail FROM Account WHERE PersonEmail = '" + csvrow[2] + "' LIMIT 1" , function(err, res) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            csvrow[3] = res.records[0].Id
            tempArray.push(csvrow);
            fastcsv.writeToPath("new.csv", tempArray, {headers: true})
            .on("finish", function() {
                console.log("Added : " + csvrow[2]);
            });
        });
    })
```

Comment: Glad it worked. If the answer was useful, please accept/upvote. Thanks

Comment: Just understand that, the way you're solving it, the new.csv file is being written time and time again, once for each line of the accounts.csv file which is the number of times the query is called. The best would be to write it only once, when all queries have finished.

Comment: that's true I just could not get the tempArray in it's completed form outside the conn.query function even though i stated it as a global prior to the function.